# Spring Scoped Prototype bean instances are equals

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I created two beans, `@Signleton` beanA that has `@Prototybe` beanB as a dependency.
To make sure that every time beanA is called beanB is initialized again I annotaed beanB with

```
Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

To make sure that everything is working fine, I made a test that verifies that if beanB is recived two times, there're two different instances of it:

```
@Test()
void testBean() throws IllegalAccessException {

    Field beanBField = ReflectionUtils.findField(BeanA.class, "beanB");
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(beanBField);

    BeanA beanA1 = applicationContext.getBean(BeanA.class);
    System.out.println(beanA1); // my.package.BeanA@4b41e4dd
    BeanB beanB1 = (PMToJupiterMapper) beanBField.get(beanA1);
    System.out.println(beanB1); // my.package.BeanB@42463763

    BeanA beanA2 = applicationContext.getBean(BeanA.class);
    System.out.println(beanA2); // my.package.BeanA@4b41e4dd
    BeanB beanB2 = (PMToJupiterMapper) beanBField.get(beanA2);
    System.out.println(beanB2); // my.package.BeanB@59f63e24

    assertEquals(beanA1, beanA2); // Is OK as expected
    System.out.println(beanB1.equals(beanB2)); // WHY IS TRUE?
    System.out.println(beanB1 == beanB2);// WHY IS TRUE?
}
```

beanA instances are the same, as expected and have the same hash.
But why in this case despite beanB hashes are different, equals and == between two instance of a bean still return true?

Comment: spring beans are singletons. I don't really understand what you are trying to do here

Comment: @Stultuske You can define scope of a bean - Singleton, Prorotype etc. Please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: Sure, but A is a singleton. How exactly do you expect a singleton to have two different objects in the same field?

Comment: both beanB1 and beanB2 should be equal, because even if it's a prototype, they're fields of a singleton bean and thus they are instantiated also only once

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino for that there's proxyMode. If you will have a look at results of System.out.println, there will be different hash

Comment: the hashcodes differ likely because spring usually wraps managed classes into interceptor classes, and thus while they aren't identical to actual classes they delegate to, they keep behavior same

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino, no, for BeanA they're equal. Please refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton or google "Scoped bean injection problem"

Comment: I'm talking about beanB. Again, your bean B is created only once -- during initialization of singleton bean A since it's a member of it. Your linked article even says as much (end of section 2) `Both beans were initialized only once, at the startup of the application context.`

Comment: Oh, just to be clear: you have two different hashes on bean B because when you call println(), that calls B's toString() method. As it is proxied, that will trigger the creation of a new bean, on which toString() will be called. However the actual B beans you get are obtained by accessing A's field. So it will be the same no matter how many time you access this field, of course

Comment: Also, it is an obviously atrocious code smell that calling methods twice on what for all intent and purpose is the same object, will actually call these methods on different objects. Spring provides proxification that enables such idiotic behaviors, but it's supposed to be used as glue resolve-a-problem-at-a-specific-point code.

Answer (score 0):

i think they must be equals spring beans are singletons

here's a definition

The singleton scope:the Spring IoC container creates exactly one instance of the object defined by that bean definition. This single instance is stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all subsequent requests and references for that named bean return the cached object.

The prototype scope
the Spring IoC container creates a new bean instance of the object every time a request for that specific bean is made. As a rule, use the prototype scope for all state-full beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans.

Answer (score 0):

When using the scope prototype, a new instance is created each time you call for the bean.
As you can see in lines:

```
System.out.println(beanB2); // my.package.BeanB@59f63e24
System.out.println(beanB1); // my.package.BeanB@42463763
```

These two beans are two different instances. 
Now two questions:

- why beanB1.equals(beanB2) is true?  this is because equals methods compare the contents of objects.
- why  (beanB1 == beanB2); is true? I think it should be false, please check again.

Comment: Hi @EFOE, for these objects equals is not implemented, so by default it compares hashcodes and references. That's why I am so confused that these objects "are" equal despite their deafault toString implementation resturns different results